# For al reves da error en Swift 3 ¿Cómo lo soluciono?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode

Actualice el xCode y estoy lleno de `warning`, ya casi todos solucionados, pero este me falta

```
for var i:Int = row-1; i >= 0; i -= 1
```

Me lanza el siguiente warning:

```
C-style for statement is deprecated and will be removed in a future version of Swift
```

Comment: No estoy seguro de lo que te voy a comentar, pero creo que el formato de i++ o i-=1 en Swift 3 lo van a quitar

Comment: Eso no es un error es un warning de que esa manera de iterar quedará obsoleta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ese tipo de `for` quedará obsoleto en `Swift 3.0`. La función equivalente sería la siguiente:

```
for i in (0...row - 1).reverse() {

}
```

o en su defecto y probablemente más correcto:

```
for i in (0..<row).reverse() {

}
```